# Android NDK & FFMPEG : findLibrary returned null

Tags: android, android-ndk, ffmpeg

I am using this  to build ffmpeg on ndk:
 [roman10's android ndk r9d - ffmpeg tutorial](http://www.roman10.net/how-to-build-ffmpeg-with-ndk-r9)

The link shows how to compile, but its not clear how to use it. Can anybody guide me? Thanks.

After ndk-build from my project root i was able to generate .so files inside `libs/armeabi` and `obj/local/armeabi`.. Now I am getting **`findLibrary returned null`**?? What to do now?

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load libavutil from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.palak.androidffmpegroman-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.palak.androidffmpegroman-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null

        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:358)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:526)
        at com.palak.androidffmpegroman.MainActivity.<clinit>(MainActivity.java:175)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2101)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

my project structure:

[image]

My `build_android.sh`

```
  #!/bin/bash
NDK=$HOME/NDK/android-ndk-r10d
SYSROOT=$NDK/platforms/android-19/arch-arm/
TOOLCHAIN=$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86
function build_one
{
sudo ./configure \
    --prefix=$PREFIX \
    --enable-shared \
    --disable-static \
    --disable-doc \
    --disable-ffmpeg \
    --disable-ffplay \
    --disable-ffprobe \
    --disable-ffserver \
    --disable-avdevice \
    --disable-doc \
    --disable-symver \
    --cross-prefix=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- \
    --target-os=linux \
    --arch=arm \
    --enable-cross-compile \
    --sysroot=$SYSROOT \
    --extra-cflags="-Os -fpic $ADDI_CFLAGS" \
    --extra-ldflags="$ADDI_LDFLAGS" \
    $ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG
make clean
make
make install
}
CPU=arm
PREFIX=$(pwd)/android/$CPU 
ADDI_CFLAGS="-marm"
build_one
```

I am using Ndk r10, ffmpeg 2.5.4, ubuntu x86.

Edit: Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH:= /home/palak/NDK/ffmpeg-2.5.4/android/arm

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE:= libavcodec
LOCAL_SRC_FILES:= lib/libavcodec-56.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE:= libavformat
LOCAL_SRC_FILES:= lib/libavformat-56.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE:= libswscale
LOCAL_SRC_FILES:= lib/libswscale-3.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE:= libavutil
LOCAL_SRC_FILES:= lib/libavutil-54.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE:= libavfilter
LOCAL_SRC_FILES:= lib/libavfilter-5.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE:= libswresample
LOCAL_SRC_FILES:= lib/libswresample-1.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Android.mk under jni folder:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := tutorial01
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := tutorial01.c
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog -ljnigraphics -lz 
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := avformat avcodec swscale avutil

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
$(call import-module,ffmpeg-2.5.4/android/arm)
```

Comment: I would only expect modules mentioned like so: `LOCAL_MODULE:= libavutil` to appear as `.so` files. Why do you think there should be a `libffmpeg.so`?

Comment: Thanks for coming, Ok, then how do you proceed further? I meant what to put in jni folder and how to do : ndk-build? Need some help.

Comment: once post your Android.mk file

Comment: Hey Ramesh I have edited my post.

Comment: Can you please do us a big favor... please make a tutorial video while compiling or making .so files. Um stucked from the last 5 days and didt get the result.. I am successfully making file as .a but not .so .. Please help me.

Comment: I will do it ... while i will be free

Comment: Dude, were you able to get this working ? I'm doing the same exact tutorial and this is my exact problem right now.

Answer (score 0):

```
LOCAL_MODULE:= libavutil
```

-->

```
LOCAL_MODULE:= avutil # libavutil.so
```

example (used to work):
https://github.com/18446744073709551615/reDroid/blob/master/jni/Android.mk

**UPDATE:**
Once again: you do not need the `lib` prefixes in library names;
 `LOCAL_MODULE:= avutil` will give you *lib**avutil**.so*

At second, what parameter do you pass to *loadLibrary()*? Again, it should be `"avutil"` for  *lib**avutil**.so*.

If you have problems, the best way is to start with the hello-jni example in the NDK (*your-ndk-dir*`/samples/hello-jni/`)

```
/* this is used to load the 'hello-jni' library on application
 * startup. The library has already been unpacked into
 * /data/data/com.example.hellojni/lib/libhello-jni.so <== !!!!!!!!!!!!!
 * at installation time by the package manager.
 */
static {
    System.loadLibrary("hello-jni");
}
```

Once the example compiles and runs, you may add your libraries to it and have your stuff work.

Comment: Can you brief me little bit?

Comment: I am getting exception after successful ndk-build :  java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load avutil from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader blah blah blah .. : findLibrary returned null

Comment: this means that the library is not found. Is it there in the apk? Sometimes in the apk there are two libs is in `lib/armeabi`  and only one in `lib/armeabi-v7a`

Comment: They all are located under lib/armeabi in my apk.

Comment: @PalakDarji is all the shared libraries are loaded?

Comment: I appreciate all help! but now my project manager has changed our way to work with ffmpeg. We are gonna create compiled static ffmpeg build to use with direct commandLine, no jni wrappers or c code.. Thnx.

Comment: I have edited my que. I am seeing Two new dir in my project.. 1) all .so files under lib/armeabi, 2) all .so file under obj/local/armeabi.. Still I am getting error: findLibrary returned null..

Comment: Hey there, I have already used 'avformat' without any prefix and suffix. But nothing helped. This is the way , I loaded my libs : System.loadLibrary("avutil") in static block.

Comment: Then start with hello-jni. A law of nature is that _all complex working systems are modifications of less complex working systems_ (and are never derived from broken systems). Start with hello-jni and modify it gradually.

Answer (score 0):

You use name `libavutil` to refer to `libavutil-54.so` during **ndk-build**. This is fine, but the runtime lib is still called **`libavutil-54.so`**. Moreover, your other modules, including `tutorial01`, know it by this name, so renaming it in `libs/armeabi` will also be wrong.

You need something like

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("avutil-54");
    System.loadLibrary("avcodec-56");
    System.loadLibrary("avformat-56");
    System.loadLibrary("swscale-3");
    System.loadLibrary("tutorial01");
}
```

In recent version of Android, the system will automatically resolve the local external references, so it's enough to call

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("tutorial01");
}
```

Comment: Hey Alex, I have managed to compile and run my project somehow.. although I have tried above solution, Actually the problem was with my Android.mk file which was resolved.. My apology to waste ur time. Thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your

```
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := avformat avcodec swscale avutil
```

with

```
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libavformat libavcodec libswscale libavutil libavfilter libswresample
```

in Android.mk in your Jni folder.

And Load the libraries like below

```
static {

  System.loadLibrary("avutil-54");
  System.loadLibrary("avcodec-56");
  System.loadLibrary("avformat-56");
  System.loadLibrary("swscale-3");
  System.loadLibrary("avfilter-5");
  System.loadLibrary("swresample-1");
  System.loadLibrary("tutorial01");

}
```

Comment: I have tried that way before! but it wasn't much helpful. Finally, I have managed to run my project by PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY libffmpeg.so way. Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: What if using the new gradle-experimental plugin for NDK build?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you are using a phone with an armeabi processor? Add the armeabiv7 in the Application.mk file and it will compile the required files for armeabiv7 phones in the libs folder.

```
APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a x86
```

This should work.